# System.exit(0) when minimize activity with fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

When i minimize my application system.exit(0) gets called. I dont know why and how to fix it.

I got a FrameLayout with a FragmentContainerView in my xml-File:

```xml
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Im replacing my FragmentContainerView with my fragment in the activity in onCreate:

```java
Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Network");

DefaultFragment fragment = new DefaultFragment();
fragment.init(graph, false);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

I created a new class so this is the only code in the activity.
Like I said, when I minimize the application from this activity I get the following log:

```
I/zygote: System.exit called, status: 0
I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
```

Please help!

Comment: How do you "minimize" it? Using che BACK button? Using the Home button? What is the expected behaviour when you want to minimize it?

Comment: @emandt you have the back, home and minimize button, so the application gets it the background. I expect that when i reopen the application it resumes on the same activity.

Comment: Usually do BACK from "initial page" means "I want to kill the App", so the it is not minimized in the same way as HOME does. HOME just Pause the Activity in the state in which it is. An App in background usually cannot do nothing due to Doze that stops all its tasks. So you cannot trust that a minimized App will be restored from its own in the excatly state as previous, and the stopped/paused/minimized state depends of how you're exiting from it.

Comment: Also when i click the home button and reopen the application system.exit gets called, so the app restarts..